# Map unique elements of vector to another set

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector containing `n` unique elements, and I want to map each unique element to another set of `n` elements. Here's an example:

```
vec <- sample(5:7, 20, replace=TRUE)
map_to <- c(11, 15, 20)
```

I want to map `5` to `11`, `6` to `15`, etc.

What's the fastest way to do this on R?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Why did it not work? It would be nice to include a seed in your Q (`set.seed(123)`), allows for comparisons of output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortest way I've found is `map_to[as.factor(vec)]`.